# How to keep commas when exporting a csv file with python for Airtable?

Tags: python, csv, airtable

I'll try to make my request as clear as possible. I'm trying to export a table written with Python in `.csv` format for Airtable.

Once my `.csv` is exported, if I open it with Excel, there is no problem, but then if I upload it to Airtable (used by my association), it doesn't tolerate the strings in which there is a comma.

The result will be :

```
prenom|nom|instrument|

jean,dupont,"violon,piano,guitar"| <-- ERROR

marie|moulin|guitar
```

instead of :

```
prenom | nom    | instrument            |
-------+--------+-----------------------+
jean   | dupont | violon, piano, guitar |
marie  | moulin | guitar                |
```

Can I fix the problem by exporting differently my csv with Python? Do you see any other solution?

This is how i exported my csv :

```
with open('CRMtest.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    linewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=":", quotechar = '"')
    for i in range(len(list_nom)):
        linewriter.writerow([row_1[i],row_2[i],row_3[i])
```

All of my row_X are strings and some of them contains comas.

For example :

```
row_1 = 'prenom','jean','marie'

row_2 = 'nom','dupont','moulin'

row_3 = 'instrument','violon, piano, guitare','guitare'
```

Comment: Use a separator other than comma...

Comment: How do you export your data to csv in the first place? Are you familiar with the standard library ``csv``?

Comment: Finally my programm seems working, i tried many things and one of them apparently fixed the problem. 

I've thought to change the separator, but Airtable refused to open the csv (it was worth than with the comas...)

Comment: I show in my first message how the csv is exported.

Comment: The code added to the question does not produce the output shown. Fixing the syntax error (missing ] on the last line), the output is for example ``jean:dupont:violon, piano, guitare`` due to ``delimiter=":"``. If you know how to set the delimiter, why don't you set it to the desired ``|``?

Comment: I've not been sufficienlty clear in my request, but anyway, my script finally works and if there is still a problem, it only comes from Airtable, so the Python script is ok. Thanks for your help, my question is answered !